# PHP export to Excel file gives me source code in columns

Tags: php, export-to-excel

I feel like I'm making a simple mistake but I can't seem to figure out what.

I have some code for exporting a mySQL table to an Excel file.

However, when I do the export, the entire HTML source code gets exported along with my data. I open the file in Excel and my table data in there but it's also got all the HTML inside.

What could be causing all the source code to be exported along with the data?

I should mention that I'm using this code as part of a Wordpress plugin I'm writing. When I test the export outside wordpress, it works fine. But when I try to export from a Wordpress admin page, I get all the extra HTML source code.

Comment: Is there a `get_header()` call anywhere in your export script, or within the theme/template being used? I'm willing to bet that the HTMl you're getting embedded is the template scaffolding.

Comment: You're basically saving your html but giving the file an extension of .xls?

Comment: @MarcB -- I actually don't see that exact function on the admin side but I imagine there's gotta be something similar. How can I look into the scaffolding issue? Or, what can I do to prevent it? I've not heard of that before.

Comment: @Mark Baker -- Yes, that's what's happening but I don't want the HTML in there.

Comment: WP assumes that all pages you're building are going to be part of the site itself. You have to specifically do a page template that does NOT output the "scaffolding" (headers/footers/menus/etc..), which WP would otherwise automatically spit out, messing up the Excel data.

Comment: K. Thanks. I'll give it a try and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'mysqlUser';
$pass = 'myUserPass';
$db = 'myDatabase';
$table = 'products_info';
$file = 'export';

$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Can not connect." . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db) or die("Can not connect.");


$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table");

// fetch a row and write the column names out to the file
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$line = "";
$comma = "";
foreach($row as $name => $value) {
    $line .= $comma . '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $name) . '"';
    $comma = ",";
}
$line .= "\n";
fputs($fp, $line);

// remove the result pointer back to the start
mysql_data_seek($res, 0);

// and loop through the actual data
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {

    $line = "";
    $comma = "";
    foreach($row as $value) {
        $line .= $comma . '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $value) . '"';
        $comma = ",";


    }
     $line .= "\n";
    fputs($fp, $line);

}

fclose($fp);
header('Content-type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');
readfile('export.csv');
```

Thanks,

Kanji